# What's the difference between below two cofigurestore in redux toolkit

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am new to Redux Toolkit and was following the docs. I was configuring the store and I saw this approach in quick overview sections https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide#simplifying-store-setup-with-configurestore

```js
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import rootReducer from './reducers'

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
})

export default store
```

but in the docs for quick start I also saw this approach https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/quick-start

```js
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import counterReducer from '../features/counter/counterSlice'

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    counter: counterReducer,
  },
})
```

Why are these two different assuming we are exporting `slicename.reducers` and one is nested using slice name while other is directly being assigned as a reducer?

Is `reducer: { counter: counterReducer, },` approach taken if there are multiple reducers and to combine them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `reducer` option of `configureStore` function can be a function or an object. The source code [configureStore.ts#L162](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/blob/v1.9.5/packages/toolkit/src/configureStore.ts#L162):

```js
if (typeof reducer === 'function') {
  rootReducer = reducer
} else if (isPlainObject(reducer)) {
  rootReducer = combineReducers(reducer) as unknown as Reducer<S, A>
}

// ... 

return createStore(rootReducer, preloadedState, composedEnhancer)
```

As you can see if you pass an object full of reducers for each state slice. It will use redux [`combineReducers`](https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers) to combine them. The `rootReducer` will be passed in the `createStore` function at the end, see [configureStore.ts#L214](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/blob/v1.9.5/packages/toolkit/src/configureStore.ts#L214).

That's the difference between them. More often, we use the second approach, dividing a state tree into multiple state slices. And combine them into a root reducer. But if your application is simple, and doesn't need to maintain a complex state, then you don't need to split the state tree, a root reducer is enough.